# ASP.NET and JQuery - Default Button Click

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET page that is basically a search form. My code for this form looks like this:

```
<form id="mainForm" runat="server">
  Search For: <asp:TextBox ID="searchTB" runat="server" /> 
  <input id="myButton" runat="server" type="button" value="Go" 
    onclick="disableButton(this);" onserverclick="myButton_Click" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function disableButton(b) {
      b.disabled = true;
      b.value = "Searching...";
    }
  </script>
</form>
```

This code works fine as long as a user manually clicks the button. However, if a user hits the "Enter" key, the search is not performed. My question is, how do I set an HTML button to the default button in an ASP.NET page when client-side scripting is involved?

Thank you!

Comment: The problem is related to the disabled=true. How do I disable the button, but still my the server side event fire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `onkeypress` event?  Bind it to the same function and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

[ASP.NET 2.0 - Enter Key - Default Submit Button](https://web.archive.org/web/20200924062349/http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2006/04/12/74951.aspx)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

For enter to work by default, your button needs to be the first one on the page and it should be type="submit" rather than type="button".

You could also try changing your input to a standard asp.net button.  If you change your javascript function to return true, the post click of the button should still work.  However to bind 2 events to the button you may need to add the client side click in your page load method.

```
myButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return disableButton(this)");
```